# How to close a Python FMX GUI App with a button click?

Tags: python, firemonkey

Is there a built-in function for closing the app via code?

How would I close the app via code instead of clicking on the closing button in the title bar?

I'm using [DelphiFMX GUI Library for Python](https://github.com/Embarcadero/DelphiFMX4Python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the following line of code in your `Button` click event:

```
Application.Terminate()
```

This will completely terminate the app and free it from the memory.

---

If you're on the `MainForm`, then you can also use the following line of code to `Close` the `MainForm` which in turn will also `Terminate` the app and free it from the memory:

```
self.Close()
```